# Listen onclick event in PyObjC

Tags: python, onclick, pyobjc

I try to display the current windows for each click on the system.

I do this code :

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace

def getwindows():
    activeAppName = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
    print activeAppName
    return

def main():
    getwindows()

main()
```

But only the current windows when i setup the script is displayed.

How can i bind this script in a loop with a click event ?

I already try to use `Turtle` but some errors appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `activeApplication` method of `NSWorkSpace` is deprecated.  The following can be used to actively probe the running applications for their active status:

```
import AppKit
import time
rl = AppKit.NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
ws = AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
for i in xrange(10):
  for app in ws.runningApplications():
    if app.isActive():
      print "active app:", app.localizedName()
  date = AppKit.NSDate.date()
  time.sleep(1)
  rl.acceptInputForMode_beforeDate_( AppKit.NSDefaultRunLoopMode, date )
```

Active means it is the receiving keyboard input.  Clicking on an application will cause it to become active.  Note that the `acceptInputForMode` method must be called so that property changes are reflected in the current app.  Run this program then click on various other applications -- you should see the active app change.

A kind of binding can be done through observers:

```
import AppKit

ws = AppKit.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
appL = ws.runningApplications()

class MyClass( AppKit.NSObject ):
  def observeValueForKeyPath_ofObject_change_context_(self,
          kpath, objid, change, context ):
    print "path change", kpath, change['new'], appL[context].localizedName()

obj = MyClass.new()
for i in xrange(len(appL)):
  appL[i].addObserver_forKeyPath_options_context_( obj,
            "isActive", AppKit.NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew, i )

date = AppKit.NSDate.date().dateByAddingTimeInterval_( 10 )
rl = AppKit.NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
rl.acceptInputForMode_beforeDate_( AppKit.NSDefaultRunLoopMode, date )

for app in appL:
  app.removeObserver_forKeyPath_( obj, "isActive" )
```

Run this program same as the last.

There are a few other properties of `NSRunningApplication` that you could probe/observe (such as `hidden`) but the list is quite short.